# VSCode: quickly switch the file path from relative to a non-relative

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to quickly switch the path of an (already) imported file from relative to non-relative and vice versa? If there is no built-in functionality, is there any extension to achieve this?

Example:

```
// Before switching
import file from './folder/file'

// After switching
import file from 'workspace/src/folder/file'
```

Note: I'm aware of `[java|type]script.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` setting. I'm asking about the situation when automatically generated path should be switched for some reason.